# web service returning reliable proxy addresses

Tags: proxy

I'm looking for a proxy service (free or subscription) that I can programmatically request a random ip from that I can use to automate some manual testing.

I'd like the service to have at least hundreds of ips it can select from to avoid repetition.

Anonymity is not required but reasonable reliability is.

Any recommendations? Searches just seem to lead me to unreliable, popup crazy, free anonymous proxies lists.

Answer (score 0):

I did come across exactly what I wanted but haven't had a chance to test it yet:

[SEO Proxies](http://www.seo-proxies.com/)

which has the API I was after. It looks to be created for SEO mobs to mass scrape search engines without capture.